# Remove rows of a Matrix in R according to a condition

Tags: r, matrix, rows

Imagine you have the following matrix in R:

```
      [,1]   [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  "A/B"    3    4    5    7
[2,]  "A/C"    8    6    7    7
[3,]  "A/B/C"  8    8    5    4
```

What is the easiest way to remove the rows where I have more than two letters on the first column? I think the rationale should be something like:

```
if nchar(matrix[,1]!=3) then remove that row
```

But I don't know how to code this. Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: If your matrix is named `m`, then `m = m[nchar(m[, 1]) <= 2, ]`.

Comment: And, FYI, a matrix can only have one data type, so it is a very poor choice when you have both character strings and numbers. You should use a data frame instead, which can have different data types in each column.

Comment: let `mat` be the name of your matrix. Then just do `mat[nchar(mat[,1])<3,]`

Comment: By "letter" do you mean character or alphabet letters (i.e. A-Z) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your matrix to a data frame, and then use `grepl` to check for a matching pattern of three or more letter:

```
df <- df[!grepl("\\w/\\w/\\w.*", df$letters),]
```

[image]

### Demo

Some of the suggestions in the comments above might also work for you, but a regex based solution has the added benefit that it is robust, and can be easily changed if your requirements change at some point in the future.

Comment: This will maintain the rows and romove the desired rows. I gues you meant to do `!grepl(...)`